# Do you get a new character trophy for every difficulty level in classic mode?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I've recently picked up SSBB, and noticed that I get a character trophy when I clear Classic Mode on easy, and a different trophy when I clear it on Normal. Two related questions:

1) Does Classic give a different trophy for all 5 difficulty levels?

2) Will clearing it on Normal earn me that character's Easy trophy too, or do I have to play each character on every difficulty if I want all trophies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one trophy for each character for Classic Mode, regardless of what difficulty you play. In addition, these are the trophies that are earned for completing Classic mode in certain ways:

- Beating Classic Mode on Very Hard gives the player the Striker Mario Trophy.
- Beating Classic Mode on Intense gives the player a trophy of Crazy Hand.
- Beating Classic Mode with 20 different characters gives the player a trophy of Master Hand.
- Beating Classic Mode with all characters gives the player the Paper Mario Trophy.
- Beating Classic Mode with all characters (including Sheik, Zero Suit Samus, Squirtle, Ivysaur, and Charizard) gives the player the Creeping Chrysanthemum trophy.

However, this last point brings up a follow-up question: Were using using Zelda/Sheik, Samus/ZSS, or Pokémon Trainer? The trophy you get upon completing Classic Mode with them is dependent on which form of the character you dealt the final blow with. For example, if you beat it on Easy using Charizard at the end, and then complete it on Normal using Squirtle at the end, you get the Charizard trophy the first time and the Squirtle trophy the second time (and a Pokémon Trainer trophy both times).

Sources: http://www.ssbwiki.com/Trophy, http://www.ssbwiki.com/Classic_Mode

Comment: I was playing zelda/shiek - that would explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember and according to [this wiki](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy), the difficulty level has nothing to do with the character trophy that you can get:

> To obtain character trophies, players must finish Classic mode with that character. To obtain characters' Final Smash trophies, players must finish All-Star mode with that character.

So you will have 2 different trophies for each character, one for each mode. Cheking a specific trophy list from that wiki, like for example the [Ice Climber trophies](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_SSBB_trophies_(Ice_Climber_series)), you can see that there are just 2 trophies for beating the modes with that character, one for Classic and another one for All-Star.

My guess is that one of those trophies that you got with the same character was not earned just for beating that specific difficulty level, you might have earned it as a bonus trophy (beating Classic mode with X characters, beating Classic mode in less than X seconds... I don't remember the bonus ones).